# How would I make this else statement work

Tags: python

My else statement wont print for this program and I'm not sure why.

```
side1 = int(input("Enter one side of a triangle : "))
side2 = int(input("Enter one side of a triangle : "))
side3 = int(input("Enter one side of a triangle : "))

if side1 != side2:
    if side2 != side3:
        if side3 != side1:
            print("This triangle is scalene")
elif side1 == side2:
        if side2 == side3:
            if side3 == side1:
                print("This triangle is equilateral")
else:
    print("This triangle is isosceles")
```

Comment: The else statement will never run because you have accounted for every case in your if and elif.

Comment: side1 and side 2 are either equal or not, there's no third case.

Comment: You need all three conditions to hold simultaneously: condition1 `and` condition2 `and` condition3.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is faulty: there is no conventional way to reach the `else`.  Look at your preceding conditions:

```
if side1 != side2:
    ...
elif side1 == side 2:
    ...
```

That covers all typical situations; any numbers you enter will fall into one of those two clauses; no further conditions of your if-elif-else will matter.

I'm not going to hand you a whole solution; you still need to work through several layers of logic flaw.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your if and elif statements already cover all possible cases as side1 can either be equal or not equal to side2. A way to fix this is to combine all your if statements like so:

```
side1 = int(input("Enter one side of a triangle : "))
side2 = int(input("Enter one side of a triangle : "))
side3 = int(input("Enter one side of a triangle : "))

if side1 != side2 and side2 != side3 and side3 != side1:
    print("This triangle is scalene")
elif side1 == side2 and side2 == side3 and side3 == side1:
    print("This triangle is equilateral")
else:
    print("This triangle is isosceles")
```